# Having issue with image resizing in html when converting to mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started learning front-end web development. I was working on my portfolio mockup and I am having issues with image sizing. I am using bootstrap framework. When i use an image with img-responsive class, the height and width of the image I upload are set automatically. Since I wanted to set the height myself, I changed the height of the image (in css file). However, now when i reduce my browser's width in order to see how my portfolio will look when in mobile view, the width resizes but the height remains the same. This makes the image look disproportional. How can i fix this? If I don't use custom height, everything is fine in mobile view.

Comment: Show us some code - maybe a JSFiddle or Codepen.

Comment: Without html and css code it is difficult to know what is wrong. Can you post some code, or as suggested by Tony create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me in my google chrome browser. As far as the mobile view and other devices this meta tag helps "meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" (refer to the meta tag in my html head element)

```css
hr {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 width: 100%;
}
.featured-work {
 color: #BCBBBB;
}
.font {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 60px;
}
.font1 {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.footer-title-fonts {
 color: #747704;
}
.name {
 margin-top: 66px;
}
.ulogo {
 margin-top: 40px;
}
.multiple-borders {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px black;
}
.multiple-borders1 {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px blue;
}
.multiple-borders2 {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px red;
}
.multiple-borders3 {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Home Page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container"> <!-- start of container class -->

      <div class="row"> <!-- start of row class -->
          
                  <!-- udacity logo -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="ulogo" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="udacity logo">
        </div>
                  <!-- end of udacity logo -->
                  <!-- start of name div -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h1 class="font name text-uppercase text-right">Jane Doette</h1> 
          <h5 class="font1 text-uppercase text-right">Front-end ninja</h5>
        </div>
                  <!-- end of name div -->
      </div> <!-- end of row class -->
     
          <hr>
                   <!-- main image -->
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <img class="img-responsive multiple-borders" src="http://placekitten.com/1170/500" alt="filler image">
          </div>
      </div>
                  <!-- end of main image -->


                  <!-- bottom 3 images -->
        <div class="row"> <!-- start of row class -->
          
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="featured-work">Featured Work</h3>
          </div>
                  <!-- First Image -->
          <div class="col-md-4"> 
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/550/400" class="img-responsive multiple-borders1" alt="filler image">
            <h2 class="footer-title-fonts text-center text-uppercase">Applify</h2>
            <h6 class="footer-title-fonts text-center">https://github.com/udacity/Appify/</h6>
          </div>
                  <!-- End of frst Image -->
                  
                  <!-- Second Image -->
          <div class="col-md-4"> 
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/550/400" class="img-responsive multiple-borders2" alt="filler image">
            <h2 class="footer-title-fonts text-center text-uppercase">Sunflower</h2>
            <h6 class="footer-title-fonts text-center">https://github.com/udacity/Sunflower/</h6>
          </div>
                  <!-- End of second Image -->
          
                  <!-- Third Image -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/550/400" class="img-responsive multiple-borders3" alt="filler image">
            <h2 class="footer-title-fonts text-center text-uppercase">Bokeh</h2>
            <h6 class="footer-title-fonts text-center">https://github.com/udacity/Bokeh/</h6>  
          </div>
                  <!-- End of Third Image -->
                  <!-- end of bottom 3 images -->

        </div> <!-- end of row class -->
    </div> <!-- end of container class -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap_css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Custom_css/P1.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Project 1</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="top-image" src="images/udacity.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
          <h1 class="text-thin">Jiwanjot Singh</h1>
          <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="images/mainimage.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2>Featured Work</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="images/arcade.jpg" alt="Placehold Image" />
          <h3 class="text-uppercase">ArcadeDemo</h3>
          <p>https://github.com/udacity/ArcadeDemo/</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="images/alarm.jpg" alt="Placehold Image" />
          <h3 class="text-uppercase">AlarmMe</h3>
          <p>https://github.com/udacity/AlarmMe/</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="images/bokeh.jpg" alt="Placehold Image" />
          <h3 class="text-uppercase">Bokeh</h3>
          <p>https://github.com/udacity/Bokeh/</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is the code. Another issue I am facing is that under the featured work section I used three images. The width of the images are the same since they are under col-md-4. But why is the height of each image different in the browser. Shouldn't the container and img-responsive classes fix that.